# Scrolling text in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a scrolling text which runs from left to right , it works perfectly fine , but I can't figure it out, how to change the size font and text color , could someone tell me please how to change the text size , font and color. Should I set the panel's background ? or the frame ? or the label ?
The question seems simple but I'm still new and learning

Here is the code :

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RunningText extends JPanel {

  int x;
  int y;
  String text;

  public RunningText() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    x = -45;
    y = 150;
    text = "DSTU";
    setSize(400, 300);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(text, x, y);
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
  }

  public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
      while (x <= getWidth()) {
        x++;
        y = getHeight() / 2;
        repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    RunningText run = new RunningText();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(run);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    run.start();

  }
}
```

Comment: You never reset the value of x back to -45. Do so before the inner while loop starts.

Comment: You should override paintComponent, not paint. you should also call super.paintComponent()  You create a label but then never use it. If you arent using the component as a container, you might consider extending JComponent instead of JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for change the color of the text use by the second time the method setColor() in the Graphics object and for change the Font use the method setFont() in the Graphics object

```java
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20)); //changes the font to sans serif, make it bold and set the font size in twenty
        g.drawString(text, x, y);
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
```

postscript: the infinite while is useless

```java
    public void start() throws InterruptedException {

        while (x <= getWidth()) {
            x++;
            y = getHeight() / 2;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

    }
```